# How do I create a custom UDP packet in scapy?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, scapy

I want to send a UDP packet with the following as the header

- destination address
- source address
- ack num
- seq num

How do I specify the fields and number of bytes required to store them?

Comment: Those are not the fields in a UDP header, which are: Source Port, Destination Port, Length, and Checksum. UDP is a very simple protocol. It doesn't have ACKs or sequence numbers.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I figured it out. I was trying to implement TCP over UDP and was looking for an easy way to test my server.

Comment: TCP and UDP are completely separate Transport Layer protocols, that each ride on top of IP.